# Почистить базу данных (django)

Tags: python, django

Есть некая модель в джанго.

Когда тестил её, в админке добавлял и удалял записи, по итогу там осталась только одна запись. Во вьюхе мне нужно получить эту запись, я думал, что получу её через `get(pk=1)`, но как оказалось у неё pk равен 6. То есть те записи, которые я вводил для теста, удалились не полностью?

Могу ли я как то обновить состояние таблицы чтобы элемент имел `pk = 1`?

P.S. Пытался через `objects.all()[:1]`, тоже не работает...

Comment: `MyModel.objects.all().first()` - для получения первого объекта

Comment: Primary key по дефолту назначаются моделям автоматически - это не порядковый номер записи в таблице, а её уникальный идентификатор и он не меняется сам по себе. Можете получить вашу запись через get(pk=6) либо object.all()[0] и поменять pk принудительно

Comment: Ясно. Просто не верно понял суть :)

Answer (score 2):

Всё суть идентификаторов в их неизменности. Не надо пытаться сбросить их к начальному значению. А чтобы получить последнюю запись, можно использовать `SomeModel.objects.last()`.